# Bitmap from Stream: Bug?

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream, jpeg

I have a pretty strange Error. I need to scale down images, scale down the quality and convert to JPEG. This all works when I save the File on disk, but it doesn't work when I save it to a Stream.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = // valid Bitmap from Disk
System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

// JPEG Encoding

System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder( System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg );
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder encoder2 = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters parameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters( 1 );
System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter parameter = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter( encoder2, qualityLevel );
parameters.Param[0] = parameter;

// Save downscaled on Disk and stream

bitmap.Save( stream, jpgEncoder, parameters );
bitmap.Save( @"C:\TestJPEG.jpg", jpgEncoder, parameters );

// some stream stuff

var bytes = ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray();
System.IO.Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream( bytes );

// Load from disk and stream

Bitmap fromDisk = new Bitmap( @"C:\TestJPEG.jpg" ); // works
Bitmap fromStream = new Bitmap( inputStream ); // crash invalid parameter no inner message or description
Bitmap fromStream2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream( inputStream ); // same error here
// also crashes if I load the "stream" named Stream
```

I can also open the converted file with Paint. 
Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I'm using .Net Framework 4.0 on Windows 7 Professional

**Edit2:**
Tried that Seek thing (Answer was deleted)

```
stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
```

It workes with the "old" stream. But i need to load it from a byte Array. Still same crash

Comment: are you closing/disposing `inputStream` at some point? Disposing a stream after constructing a `Bitmap` from it is a common mistake. The stream must be kept alive as long as the `Bitmap` is kept alive.

Comment: No, not yet. It's still in a Unit Test trying to get it to run.

Comment: Have you tried `Image.FromStream` instead of the `Bitmap` constructor? Also, what happens if you Dispose `bitmap` after the save to file?

Comment: Yes already tried, i should add it quick. Same error

Comment: Your code works for me. I executed the following in LINQPad, no exception: http://pastebin.com/Qqz8mXUv. Are you sure you showed us all relevant parts of your code? What exactly is `GetEncoder` doing? What's the value of `qualityLevel`? Maybe you could upload your picture?

Comment: Rather than `new Bitmap(...)` what about `Image.FromStream(...)`, might be the same but I've never had an issue with the latter?

Comment: @Lloyd: Already tried, see OP edit ;p

Comment: BTW: When trying out your code, I was getting the `Invalid parameter` exception at the line that saves the bitmap. The problem was the value I passed to `new EncoderParameter`. Are you sure you are getting the exception at the line you are saying?

Comment: @ArndtBieberstein: What happens if you comment out the saving to file bit? As Daniel's sample works, this is about the only real difference I can see. Pretty silly limitation if that is indeed so.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I tried your code it works! But I can't see a difference? You can post it as an answer. Yes getting the error at the new Bitmap( inputStream ); line.

Comment: @leppie Nothing changed

Comment: I updated my answer. I also incorporated the saving to and loading from disk. It still works on my side. I guess the `qualityLevel` parameter is the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Well that's actually a really good question i would also like to know.

Comment: @ArndtBieberstein: Haha, ok. Try using *your* code and just change `qualityLevel` to be a `long`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Wow that is actually the missing puzzle piece. I know this Function is expecting a `long` value parameter, but i did't thought that could be the reason. Very good hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"c:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\daniel.hilgarth\Desktop\Unbenannt.bmp");

ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(x => x.FormatDescription == "JPEG");
Encoder encoder2 = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
EncoderParameters parameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters( 1 );
EncoderParameter parameter = new EncoderParameter( encoder2, 50L );
parameters.Param[0] = parameter;

System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save( stream, jpgEncoder, parameters );
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Temp\TestJPEG.jpg", jpgEncoder, parameters);

var bytes = ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray();
System.IO.Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Bitmap fromDisk = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\TestJPEG.jpg");
Bitmap fromStream = new Bitmap(inputStream);
```

There are a few differences to your code. Which one causes your problem is up to you to find out, I guess:

- I used `50L` as `qualityLevel`. When using `1`, `2`, `50` or `100`, I was getting an `ArgumentException` "Parameter is not valid". As I don't know the type or value of your `qualityLevel` variable that can very well be the problem.
- I replaced your `GetEncoder` method. I don't know what your method does exactly, so it could be the problem, but I doubt it.

Comment: I guess `qualityLevel` needs to be a 64-bit integer, aka `long` (or `ulong`). And this causes the problem.

Comment: @leppie: Yes, I think so, too. The interesting thing is, that this constructor accepts also `byte` and `short` values. When passing the exact same value as `byte` or `short` it will lead to an exception. A poorly designed API in my eyes.

Comment: `GetEncoder` does pretty much the same as `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(x => x.FormatDescription == "JPEG");`

Comment: Looking at the decompilation of `EncoderParameter` reveals a *really* weird class. The ctor used here (that takes a `long`) casts it to `int` without first checking if it fits! I can only assume this was written as the thinnest of thin wrappers around the existing GDI+ code...