# System.Drawing.Image.FromStream() "Parameter is not valid" on Windows XP

Tags: c#

The following works fine on my Windows 7 development machine, however when run on Windows XP I get and exception stating "Parameter is not valid" on the last line?

```
private string base64String = "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";

byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image b = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);
```

This base64 string string works fine on both operating systems.  Its is also an icon, but smaller in size:

```
"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"
```

Comment: What format is the data in bytes[]? Was it an image file read directly from disc, or an existing image object? Also, are you targeting the same version of .NET on both machines? The issue might be that your image format is supported in one scenario but not both. Perhaps try repeating the test with a more "safe" format such as bitmap and see if it works that way.

Comment: To verify that your byte array is valid, you could try writing it to a file, and then see if you can open the file as a valid image.

Comment: You could also try resetting the stream back to the beginning before creating the image:
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: @mbeckish - apparently, by using the ctor overload this sets the memory stream to the beginning

Comment: It might have to do with how the original image was encoded into base64String.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14769874/21727).

Comment: @mbeckish I **highly** doubt it has anything to do with the base64 string. It works flawlessly in Win7, and saving the raw bytes to disk works correctly as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - But couldn't working flawlessly in Win7 just meant that the encoding is supported by Win7, but not WinXP?

Comment: No. Base64 is Base64. It has nothing to do with image formats.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I meant the encoding of the image data (before it is converted to base 64) might not be WinXP compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XP is truly getting long in the tooth.  The one thing it is missing is version 1.10 of gdiplus.dll, the update to GDI+ that first shipped with Vista.  Lots of fixes in that version, for one it now actually supports ImageFormat.Icon.

Your image data represents an .ico file.  Use the Icon(Stream) constructor instead.  You may still have a problem with the 24bpp icons, I have no way to check that anymore.

Comment: Nice job, Hans. There are several other instances of questions about this error out there and none of them really appeared to be resolved. As you can probably see from my deleted answer, I was getting close, but after it was deleted I suddenly didn't care anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Seek(0,0);
        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        data = ms.ToArray();          
    }
```

i want to access that data outside the bracket.how to do

Comment: Hi, sagivasan, and welcome to StackExchange. You've put your question as an answer to someone else's question; it'd be best to start a new question instead. (Hint: all you need to do is declare `data` outside the `using` block. You also don't need to assign `new byte[0]` to it when you declare it, by the way.)