# Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

Using C# MVC 5 to pull data from active directory from a search. One of which I need it to pull the thumbnail photo.

So my LDAP connection grabs initial data and does the conversion of the thumbnail to byte[] successfully, at least it looks like it from debugging. Then when I try to convert the byte array to an image I get an "parameter is not valid" error.

Here's my Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string userName, string searchFilter)
{
    /**********Establish Connection********/
    DirectoryEntry dir = createDirectoryEntry();
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
    /****Refer to class constructor****/


    /********Create the List to store results in***************/
    List<ADUser> Users = new List<ADUser>();
    string DisplayName = "", SAMAccountName = "", Mail = "", Description = "", Department = "", TelephoneNumber = "", Fax = "";
    byte[] ThumbnailPhoto;
    string searchFilters = searchFilter.ToString();
    /*******Filter parameters************/
    if (searchFilters == "1")
    {
        search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(&(anr=" + userName + "* )(displayName=*)(sn=*)))";
        //(&(department=" + userName + "* )(displayName=*)(sn=*))(&(telephoneNumber=" + userName + " )(displayName=*)(sn=*))
    }
    else if (searchFilters == "2")
    {
        search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(&(department=" + userName + "* )(displayName=*)(sn=*)))";
    }
    else if (searchFilters == "3")
    {
        search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(&(telephoneNumber=" + userName + "* )(displayName=*)(sn=*)))";
    }
    SearchResultCollection searchresult = search.FindAll();
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Displayname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Mail");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Description");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("TelephoneNumber");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Fax");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Department");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");
    /*****************Filtering and populating the List****************/

    if (searchresult != null)
    {
        foreach (SearchResult iResult in searchresult)
        {
            ADUser userAttributes = new ADUser("", "", "", "", "", "", "", null);

            foreach (string PropertyName in iResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                foreach (Object key in iResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties[PropertyName])
                {
                    try
                    {


                        switch (PropertyName.ToUpper())
                        {
                            case "DISPLAYNAME":
                                DisplayName = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.Name = DisplayName;
                                break;

                            case "SAMACCOUNTNAME":
                                SAMAccountName = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.DomainUserName = SAMAccountName;
                                break;

                            case "MAIL":
                                Mail = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.EmailAddress = Mail;
                                break;

                            case "DESCRIPTION":
                                Description = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.JobDescription = Description;
                                break;

                            case "TELEPHONENUMBER":
                                TelephoneNumber = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.TelephoneNumber = TelephoneNumber;
                                break;

                            case "FAX":
                                Fax = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.FaxNumber = Fax;
                                break;

                            case "DEPARTMENT":
                                Department = key.ToString();
                                userAttributes.Department = Department;
                                break;

                            case "THUMBNAILPHOTO":
                                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                                bf.Serialize(ms, key);

                                ThumbnailPhoto = ms.ToArray();
                                userAttributes.ThumbnailPhoto = ThumbnailPhoto;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            Users.Add(userAttributes);
        }

        return View(Users);
    }

    return View();
}
```

My constructor:

```
public class ADUser
    {
        private string name;
        private string domainUserName;
        private string emailAddress;
        private string jobDescription;
        private string telephoneNumber;
        private string faxNumber;
        private string department;
        private byte[] thumbnailPhoto;

        public ADUser(string name, string domainUserName, string emailAddress, string jobDescription, string telephoneNumber, string faxNumber, string department, byte[] thumbnailPhoto)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.domainUserName = domainUserName;
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
            this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
            this.faxNumber = faxNumber;
            this.department = department;
            this.thumbnailPhoto = thumbnailPhoto;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string DomainUserName
        {
            get { return domainUserName; }
            set { domainUserName = value; }
        }

        public string EmailAddress
        {
            get { return emailAddress; }
            set { emailAddress = value; }
        }

        public string JobDescription
        {
            get { return jobDescription; }
            set { jobDescription = value; }
        }

        public string TelephoneNumber
        {
            get { return telephoneNumber; }
            set { telephoneNumber = value; }
        }

        public string FaxNumber
        {
            get { return faxNumber; }
            set { faxNumber = value; }
        }

        public string Department
        {
            get { return department; }
            set { department = value; }
        }

        public byte[] ThumbnailPhoto
        {
            get { return thumbnailPhoto; }
            set { thumbnailPhoto = value; }
        }
```

And now my View;

```
@model List<webby.Helpers.ADUser>
@using System.Drawing;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Directory";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
        <h3>Directory</h3>
        <p>
            Here you will be able to search through the directory to find people that you are looking for.
            You can search by the person's name, their department or by their location.
        </p>
        <p>
            For a printable version please <a href="/Content/PDF/internal_telephone_directory.pdf" target="_blank">click here.</a>
        </p>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directory", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <p>
                Search Employee: @Html.TextBox("userName")<br />
                <input type="radio" name="searchFilter" id="rdUser" value="1" checked />
                By User
                @*<input type="radio" name="searchFilter" id="rdDept" value="2" />
                    By Department
                    <input type="radio" name="searchFilter" id="rdExt" value="3" />
                    By Extension<br />*@
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </p>
        }

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directory", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" />
            </p>
        }


        <table class="table">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f3f3';" onmouseout="    this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';">
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TelephoneNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.ThumbnailPhoto != null)
                            {

                                using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(item.ThumbnailPhoto))
                                {
                                    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    Bitmap.FromStream(s);
                                }

                            }
                        </td>
                        @*<td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")
                            </td>*@
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>

    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Cheers

Edit: Its in a hexadecimal format of 0x00, would this have anything to do with it?[image]

Comment: When using LDAP I store the small pictures in base64 format. Yes - it takes more space but parsing is really fast and I do not have such problems.

Comment: `Bitmap.FromStream` shouldn't you first create a new instance of Bitmap before assigning FromStream(s) I am just curious what the difference would be here is a `SO` post you can look at too that may help lead you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769874/bitmap-from-stream-bug

Comment: I've tried creating a new instance, no luck :(

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Figured it out on my own. When the image converted over to base64 string it converted some extra information. I substringed I think the first 9 characters (or more, don't remember) and it then worked.